# How do you reverse a strong_ordering?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Is there an easier way to achieve the effect of this function?

```
strong_ordering reverse(strong_ordering v) {
    if (v > 0)
        return strong_ordering::less;
    else if (v < 0)
        return strong_ordering::greater;
    else
        return v;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yep:

```
strong_ordering reverse(strong_ordering v)
{
    return 0 <=> v;
}
```

Which is [literally specified as what you want](http://eel.is/c++draft/cmp#strongord-7):

> *Returns*: `v < 0 ? strong_­ordering​::​greater : v > 0 ? strong_­ordering​::​less : v`.

This follows the general principle that `x <=> y` and `y <=> x` are opposites, and `v <=> 0` is just an identity operation for `v`.

Comment: Replacing the `0` with either `strong_ordering::equal` or `strong_ordering::equivalent` would also work, right?

Comment: i use the clang 11.0.0 compiler, and get a invalid operands to binary expression error. does the the compiler not support this feature yet?

Comment: @nullptr clang 10 isn't even released yet.... but both clang and gcc do support this on trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/kDQxFY

Comment: @ShadowRanger No, it would not. `strong_ordering` is not `<=>`-able with itself, only against `0`.

Comment: @Barry so `strong_ordering` doesn't have a strong ordering?

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, I don't really know that I want to go down the path of `strong_ordering` having a `strong_ordering`, `weak_ordering` having a `strong_ordering`, but `partial_ordering` having a `partial_ordering`, you know?

Comment: @Barry: Good to know. It feels weird to compare special types to `0` if there is another option, but I guess there isn't. It's `NULL` all over again, whee!

Comment: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::strong_ordering' and 'int')

Comment: @nullptr The compiler you're using probably doesn't support this, support for `<=>` is very recent. But as I showed earlier, trunk on both clang and gcc do support this now (but no official releases do yet).